# How to correctly deploy a Laravel application on XAMPP Apache?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, xampp

I am pretty new in **Laravel** and I am finding the following problem.

I have put my application in this folder:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\HotelRegistration\
```

Starting it via the statment:

```
php artisan serve
```

it is correctly started here: http://127.0.0.1:8000

For some reason I need to run it with **XAMPP Apache** server instead the one provided by **php artisan serve**

So I started **Apache** from XAMPP but trying to open:

```
http://127.0.0.1:80/HotelRegistration/
```

but so the application can't start and I obtain the list of directory and file contained in this folder.

Why? What is wrong? What am I missing? Maybe something related to virtual host? How can I fix this issue?

Tnx

Comment: you have apache configured to use 8080 port? by default it will run on the 80 port

Comment: @LordNeo I have modified my original post

Comment: Ok, thing is, the php artisan serve command doesn't serve that folder but the public one inside, so if you open that you should see your app

Answer (score 2):

`php artisan serve` creates a web server that shows the `public` folder of your app.

As a good practice, you should setup your hosting to show that public folder while hidding the rest of the program from unwanted visitors.

Check this links about it:

https://medium.com/laravel-news/the-simple-guide-to-deploy-laravel-5-application-on-shared-hosting-1a8d0aee923e

https://deployer.org/blog/how-to-deploy-laravel

For development, that isn't too much of a trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below to run your application. But it can fail to load the basic css file.

```
http://localhost/HotelRegistration/public/
```

Hope its help you.

Comment: Then check routes/web.php page add the below code if not added.Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Answer (score 0):

Solved by myself,
I create a virtual host in Apache and using this URL works